# How to make UIScrollView load data as scrolling happens

Tags: ios6, uiscrollview

I have an IOS application designed for ipad. In one page, I display a report to the user and the report requires 5000 UILabels to be rendered on the screen inside a UIScrollView. This causes application to crash due to being out of memory. I know that UITableView has the functionality for loading content on demand. How can I make scroll view render only certain content and as the scrolling happens remove the content that got invisible and add the content that should be visible?

Comment: what you have requested is exactly the point of using a UITableView or a UICollectionView. You should use these instead of a UIScrollView, and you can handle any number of data elements.

Comment: I have a requirement to use UIScrollView. Otherwise I wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: it would be useful for us to understand why you must use a UIScrollView. you're going to end up writing a lot of custom logic to get the same functionality that is already built into collection views.

Comment: You do realise that UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, right? So you can use it and still fulfill your requirement.

Comment: I understand but, how? Everybody says this is possible that is possible but no one seems to tell how to achieve.

Comment: Neo, it would be really helpful if you explained what you are trying to do in some detail, instead of just insisting that UIScrollView is used in a solution. Often it turns out that there are other tools that do the job better. In particular: It often turns out that UITableView and UICollectionView do the job better. Both are subclasses of UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way you can reconfigure it to use a table view with custom rows, perhaps rows that consist of several labels? That model supports load on demand and resource reuse in a very natural way...

Perhaps you can be more specific on your screen layout?

Comment: No. Using UIScrollView is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-cycle (i.e., reuse) the labels just like a table view recycles its table cells. This is sometimes referred to as "tiling" subviews. Tiling allows you to display more than will fit into memory.

I recommend watching WWDC 2012 Session 104. This session's tutorial creates a photo app that tiles image views in a UIScrollView. Although the photo app scrolls pages of content, rather than a grid of items, I think the video could be relevant to your app.

Here's a very brief overview of the tutorial applied to your specific case:

(1.) declare iVars that keep track of your labels:

```
NSMutableSet *recycledLabels;
NSMutableSet *visibleLabels;
```

(2.) implement a method that fetches a re-usable label:

`- (UILabel *)dequeueRecycledLabel;`

(3.) implement a method that does the tiling:

```
- (void)tileLabels; // this will add/remove labels from the scroll view
```

(4.) set your scroll view's delegate and call tileLabels in the scrollViewDidScroll: delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self tileLabels];
}
```

The WWDC video will help you fill in the details, which I think are applicable to your case. However, you will have to do plenty of improvising in order to make it work for your specific case. This may not be easy; but its doable.

At the end of the video, tiling with CATileLayer is discussed. I'll be honest, I didn't understand that part. But I don't think it's applicable in your case because you're not displaying large images.

Comment: I couldn't find the video. Could you provide url?

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented dynamic content loading. The method I implemented is **scrollViewDidScroll**.
Inside this method I determined the direction of scroll by the following

```
bool isUp = (currentOffset.y > lastScrollOffset);
```

Then I determined the visible content rectangle by the following.

```
CGRect visibleContentRect;
visibleContentRect.origin = scrollView.contentOffset;
visibleContentRect.size = scrollView.bounds.size;
```

Then I had an array of View Elements and each knew its place in the scroll view because of their frame being set. Long story short, each time scroll happened, I determined the views whose frame either intersected or contained by visible content frame. I added those views to the scroll view. I also determined the ones that disappeared and removed them from scroll view and I also set those views to nil and recreated them. Once **[scrollView addSubview:view]** method is called, then view gets more space in the memory because it gets visible. **[view removeFromSuperView]** method doesn't deallocate that space. That's why setting the view to nil and recreating it is necessary.